# QGIS Project to Raster (Geotiff)

Tags: qgis, postgis, geotiff-tiff, tiles, gdal2tiles

I've a question about rendering a qgis project (src: postgis) into raster files (e.g. geotiff).

My Goal is it to render my qgis project into 256x256 tiles for Mapnik.
I know there are a lot of python scripts which can do that, but I want to use gdal2tiles (it's better performance). So I need big Geotiff files in the max. zoom level as input for gdal2tiles. For example 2x2km (14.000px x 14.000px).

The QGIS Print-Composer can't do that for me. Using the "cmd" command for making high resolution image ("qgis --project x.qgs --snaphot --width --height.." and so on) doesn't work with that high number of pixel.

Does someone has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into qtiles plugin? Looks like what you're after.

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qtiles/